# How can i create a drop down menu by fetching data from the database in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress

[image]

I want to create a dropdown menu with aaaa,bbbb,aaaa,cccc.

This is what I have but it returns an empty menu.

```
<form method="POST">
  <br><br><label for="selections">Make a selection: </label>

  <select id="selections" name="selections" required>

<?php
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT columndata FROM mytable"));
  foreach ($results as $pointer) {
  echo "<option value='$pointer'>$pointer</option>";
  }
?>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: try printing the values for $results. get_results returns a multi-dimension array and $pointer should be an array in itself.

Comment: Expanding on @pinaki inciteful comment, try `echo "<option value='$pointer[0]'>$pointer[0]</option>";` That should show you columndata.

Comment: `$pointer->columndata`

Answer (score -1):

Please try below modify code:

```
<form method="POST">
  <br><br><label for="selections">Make a selection: </label>

  <select id="selections" name="selections" required>

<?php
global $wpdb;
//Add prefix before in your table name
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT columndata FROM wp_mytable");
  foreach ($results as $pointer) {
    //Result from query in object so need to change your variable $pointer 
    echo "<option value='$pointer->columndata'>$pointer->columndata</option>";
  }
?>
  </select>
</form>
```